# Конфликт с RxPermission

Tags: android, gradle

Хочу добавить библиотеку [tbruyelle/RxPermissions](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions) в свой проект. Следую советам этой статьи - [RxPermissions: The easiest way to Handle Android M Permissions](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/rxpermissions-the-easiest-way-to-handle-android-m-permissions-761fe8a6c3e9). Но при попытке вызвать метод `rxPermissions.request()` над ним всплывает окно с ошибкой `Cannot access class 'io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies`. А метод `subscribe` и вовсе отсутствует. В чем может быть причина?

build.gradle

```
repositories {
    //For YandexMap
    maven { url "http://maven.google.com/" }
    //For RxPermission
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
// rx - network
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'

    // rx
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.20'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.4.0'

    //RxPermission
    implementation 'com.github.tbruyelle:rxpermissions:0.12'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотека использует более новую версию RxJava. Замените зависимости на следующие:

```
    // rx - network
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava3:2.9.0'

    // rx
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.7'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    implementation("io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxkotlin:3.0.0")
```

И обновите импорты по всем проекту.